# How I can create a dynamically label change?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've many Models to set Information Labels, but that looks ugly. How I can create this code in short form?

```
case "2er Coupé":
  auto BMW_2erCoupé = new auto(30.700f, 1.850f, 5, 4.461f, 420);
  price_result_lbl.Text = BMW_2erCoupé.getSetPrice.ToString(euro);
  weight_result_lbl.Text = BMW_2erCoupé.getSetWeight.ToString(kg);
  seats_result_lbl.Text = BMW_2erCoupé.getSetSeats.ToString();
  length_result_lbl.Text = BMW_2erCoupé.getSetLength.ToString(lenght);
  power_result_lbl.Text = BMW_2erCoupé.getSetPower.ToString(ps);
  modellView_img.Image = Properties.Resources._2erCoupé;
  break;
case "330e Limousine":
  auto BMW_330eLimousine = new auto(51.550f, 2.300f, 5, 4.709f, 292);
  price_result_lbl.Text = BMW_330eLimousine.getSetPrice.ToString(euro);
  weight_result_lbl.Text = BMW_330eLimousine.getSetWeight.ToString(kg);
  seats_result_lbl.Text = BMW_330eLimousine.getSetSeats.ToString();
  length_result_lbl.Text = BMW_330eLimousine.getSetLength.ToString(lenght);
  power_result_lbl.Text = BMW_330eLimousine.getSetPower.ToString(ps);
  modellView_img.Image = Properties.Resources._330eLimousine;
  break;
```

Comment: If `BMW_2erCoupé` and `BMW_330eLimousine` are of the same type, then you can create method with such parameter (see also [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)), which will assign new texts. Image would have to be another parameter.

Comment: I was quite confused for a moment there and thought that you had started mixing C code in with your C#. Normally we'd write a class name `Auto`, not `auto`, which looks suspiciously like the C `auto` keyword. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor like this using types needed and relevant names instead of valueX with a lambda in the method before the switch:

```
Action<float, float, float, float, float, Image> initialize
  = (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, image) =>
  {
    var instance = new auto(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5);
    price_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetPrice.ToString(euro);
    weight_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetWeight.ToString(kg);
    seats_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetSeats.ToString();
    length_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetLength.ToString(lenght);
    power_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetPower.ToString(ps);
    modellView_img.Image = Image;
  };
```

That you can use like this:

```
case "2er Coupé":
  initialize(30.700f, 1.850f, 5, 4.461f, 420, Properties.Resources._2erCoupé);
  break;

case "330e Limousine":
  initialize(51.550f, 2.300f, 5, 4.709f, 292, Properties.Resources._330eLimousine);
  break;
```

If you want to get the auto instance:

```
Func<float, float, float, float, float, Image, auto> initialize
  = (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, image) =>
  {
    var instance = new auto(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5);
    price_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetPrice.ToString(euro);
    weight_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetWeight.ToString(kg);
    seats_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetSeats.ToString();
    length_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetLength.ToString(lenght);
    power_result_lbl.Text = instance.getSetPower.ToString(ps);
    modellView_img.Image = Image;
    return instance;
  };
```

You can also create a local or a class method instead of a lambda :

```
void or auto InitializeAutoAndControls(float value1, 
                                       float value2, 
                                       float value3, 
                                       float value4, 
                                       float value5,
                                       Image image)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: If you insist on constructing your object using multiple primitive parameters, I would strongly recommend the use of named parameters (which obviously only helps if you use proper names rather than "value1" and the like).  Personally, I'd rather read this sort of data from a configuration file (e.g., JSON, XML, or _maybe_ SQLite).